# Passing Pointers Between Lex and Yacc

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I have regex in my .l file that grabs a variable name.  I run that name through a function to get a pointer for it and then try to return that pointer.  In the transition between lex and yacc, the pointer gets changed somehow.  This does not happen when I do the same thing when detecting strings:

```
\"([^"]+)\"                        yylval = removeQuotes(yytext); return STRING;
[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*                   yylval = returnVar(yytext); return VAR;
%%

long removeQuotes(char* str)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; str[i]!='\0'; i++){
        str[i-1] = str[i];
    }
    str[i-2] = '\0';

    return (long)str;
}

long returnVar(char* name){
    return (long)name;
}
```

STRING works and will allow me to use strings as I like in my program.  VAR does not pass the pointer to yacc correctly, so when I try to use the pointer to grab the variable name string in yacc, it obviously can't find the same string.  Does anyone know why it is not passing the pointer as I expect?  Is there something about making the changes to the input in removeQuotes that affects the pointer at all?

EXAMPLE:
returnVar passes the pointer 39035008
yacc shows 39051408

Comment: Maybe VAR is a reserved word on Lex or yacc?

Comment: Tried adjusting for that just now.  Didn't seem to change anything unfortunately.

Comment: How did you notice the difference? printf in both at the same time?

Comment: I put printf statements in returnVar (in the lex file) and in the accessing function in my yacc file.

Comment: why do you need to return a `long`?

Answer (score 1):

`yytext` is a pointer into lex's internal scanning buffer, so it is only valid until the next call to `yylex` which will likely overwrite the buffer with different data.  As such, you shou *NEVER* store it into yylval and try to use it in the yacc code as you may see it randomly "corrupted" with data from subsequent tokens.  Instead, if you want to return a string from lex, you need to allocate some other memory for the string(s), copy the characters from yytext to there and return a pointer to that instead.